# PHP Fatal Error / Spotify Web Api

Tags: php, spotify

My script runs into an error - can someone help me on this? For me it looks like, that something is not okay with the username?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SpotifyWebAPI\\SpotifyWebAPIException' with message 'An unknown error occurred.' in /mnt/webp/b3/44/5462244/htdocs/SpotifyTest/src/Request.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/webp/b3/44/5462244/htdocs/SpotifyTest/src/Request.php(188): SpotifyWebAPI\\Request->parseBody('<html><body><h1...', 400)
#3 /mnt/webp/b3/44/5462244/htdocs/SpotifyTest/testfile.php(68): SpotifyWebAPI\\SpotifyWebAPI->getUserPlaylist('lillabj\\xC3\\xB6rn', '0WXsElmPC8aEGzr...')
#4 {main}
thrown in /mnt/webp/b3/44/5462244/htdocs/SpotifyTest/src/Request.php on line 38
```

I think it is this line ->

```
SpotifyWebAPI->getUserPlaylist('**llabj\\xC3\\xB6rn**',.....
```

I get the username from a mysql table like this

```
$USERPL = $pl['user_name'];
```

Would be great if some can give me some help.

Comment: Bad news: you're storing garbage in mysql. `lillabjörn` should be stored as-is, not as something `llabj\\xC3\\xB6rn` weirdly encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to special characters in the username, the `\\xC3\\xB6` part should be an "ö" so the full username is "lillabjörn".

When you run another user request with the same username in the Spotify Web API Console you can see that it's URL encoded in the actual request sent, https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-users-profile/?user_id=lillabj%C3%B6rn (click the link to see it).

Try URL encoding the username in all user related calls, for example:

```
$api->getUserPlaylist(urlencode('lillabjörn'), 'playlist_id');
```